# How to downgrade from Lollipop to Kitkat?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, downgrade, android-one

I am using Spice AndroidOne. When I purchased it, there was Kitkat in it. It automatically requested for Lollipop update which I have granted. Later it has requested for Marshmallow update. When I tried to update it, it has given an error.

Now Android OS is eating all my data (3G) in one day without my permission.

How to rectify it. And also I want to go back to Kitkat version.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you done any research for downgrading at all? Because the first thing that shows up at Google is [this video that shows you how to do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W9Co-2QBRZU)

Comment: Your question is way too broad. Either decide to rectify data consumption issue or to downgrade to KitKat. For whichever case you choose to,  tell what have you attempted so far?  Furthermore, give us the screenshots of Settings -> Data usage -> 3G as well as Wi-Fi, only for the data consumption issue.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you cannot downgrade from the newest version of Android to an older version, unless you root or modify your device's permissions. Ask your carrier to see if they can flash a new ROM to your device.

Comment: What "permissions" of the device need to be modified for that? First time I hear this. Usually you just have to find a matching ROM (see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)) and flash that – downgrade, upgrade, or just "something different" should not matter.

Comment: this is not true at all ,this is an android device with unlocked boot-loader and have no security to avoid downgrades ,an older rom can flashed using the SP Flash tool like any other mtk device without root and without editing "permissions"